# Comment désigne-t-on un(e) « pencil tower » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, mots-composés, métaphore

Dans un [article](https://www.cnn.com/style/article/steinway-skyscaper-interior-design/index.html) sur la/le *Steinway Tower* (sur un lot de 32x61m, 435 mètres de haut, rapport de forme de 1:24 ; [critiques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/111_West_57th_Street#Critical_reception)) on indique qu'il s'agit d'un(e) [*pencil tower*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_tower), probablement dans le sens de [*pencil-thin*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pencil-thin), la comparaison avec l'objet.

- A-t-on un équivalent dans le vocabulaire de l'architecture ?
- Comment choisit-on couramment de nommer ça ?
- Va-t-on accoler le terme choisi à « tour », « gratte-ciel », ou «
  immeuble de grande hauteur » ?

Comment: En français, on dirait plutôt unE *pencil tower*. Comme souvent le genre de mot anglais est celui de son équivalent français (une tour).

Comment: @XouDo J'ai déjà fait cette remarque dans le [chat]. Tu aurais dû dire "En France, on dirait plutôt.." au lieu de "En français, on dirait plutôt...", l'OP étant indubitablement aussi francophone que toi et moi.

Comment: @viande-à-chien Oui, le sujet est nuancé, c'est pour ça que je mentionnais "comme souvent" car ce n'est pas toujours le cas. Et pour moi aussi c'est *une deadline*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si je devais qualifier un bâtiment de ce style, je dirais ***une tour [filiforme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/filiforme)***.

[L'Express](https://www.lexpress.fr/actualites/1/monde/une-nouvelle-generation-de-gratte-ciel-filiformes-change-la-skyline-de-new-york_1704101.html) (Gratte-ciel filiforme)

[La Presse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201505/18/01-4870627-central-park-deviendra-t-il-central-dark.php) (idem)

On trouve aussi ***tour-aiguille***.

[Lumières de la ville](https://lumieresdelaville.net/paroles_urbs/new-york-et-le-phenomene-des-tours-aiguilles-par-julie-gimbal/)

*Tour crayon* n'inspire pas vraiment cette idée de finesse mais plutôt une extrémité en pointe, comme la [tour de la Part-Dieu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_Part-Dieu) à Lyon, qui n'est pas particulièrement **élancée**.

Comment: il y a aussi utilisation de l'adjectif "mince" et le terme "tour crayon" est utilisé dans [cet article](https://www.batimag.ch/technique/new-york-la-construction-du-gratte-ciel-le-plus-mince-du-monde-est-achevee-4671) "Longiligne" pourrait aussi être utilisé

Comment: @qqjkztd L'article en question n'est pas crédible. Quelques expressions étranges, souvent calquées de l'anglais, ("éléments marquants de la **ligne d'horizon**", "La Steinway Tower se veut une **déclaration** puissante", "les prix, eux, sont particulièrement **opulents**", "Quant au penthouse **sommital**") trahissent une traduction mot à mot, probablement automatique, d'un article de presse originellement en anglais. Il m'a été facile de le retrouver: [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/steinway-tower-intl-scli/index.html)

Comment: oui en effet après deuxième lecture ça ressemble bien à une traduction automatique, bien vu. Sinon il y a le mot "allongement" dont la déf aéronautique est le ratio entre l'envergure et la corde, ou dans le cas d'une tour, ratio base/hauteur.

Comment: et peut-être qu'une tour élancée, comme mentionné en fin de réponse, est l'adjectif qui décrit le mieux la tour en question. Filiforme laisse penser à ces antennes radio extrêmement légères, de plusieurs centaines de m de haut stabilisées par des câbles ancrés au sol.

Comment: élancé reste l'adjectif d'élancement, qui possède une définition architecturale bien précise en tant que substantif, mais en tant qu'adjectif il est utilisé de manière plus générale sans connotation technique